# Finding the latest in grouping

Tags: vba, excel

I have several hundred cells. I want to find the latest in the grouping. For instance i have the following data:

- 233400-003-02
- 233400-002-03
- 233400-002-02
- 233400-002-01
- 233400-001-04
- 233400-001-03
- 233400-001-02
- 233400-001-01

The last number defines the revision. I want to keep only the greatest number or the latest revision. so far I have

```
For j = 9 To i Step 1
    Dim Idstring As String

    If Len(Cells(j, 1)) = 13 Then
        Idstring = Left(Cells(j, 1), 10)
        Cells(j, 5) = Idstring
    ElseIf Len(Cells(j, 1)) = 16 Then
        Idstring = Left(Cells(j, 1), 10)
        Cells(j, 5) = Idstring
    ElseIf Len(Cells(j, 1)) = 17 Then
        Idstring = Left(Cells(j, 1), 14)
        Cells(j, 5) = Idstring
    ElseIf Len(Cells(j, 1)) = 20 Then
        Idstring = Left(Cells(j, 1), 14)
        Cells(j, 5) = Idstring
    End If


    If Cells(j, 5) = Cells(j - 1, 5) Then


        If Len(Cells(j, 1)) = 16 Then
            Cells(j, 5).EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf Len(Cells(j, 1)) = 20 Then
            Cells(j, 5).EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf Right(Cells(j, 1), 1) < Right(Cells(j + 1, 1), 1) Then
            Cells(j, 5).EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf Right(Cells(j, 1), 1) > Right(Cells(j + 1, 1), 1) Then
            Cells(j + 1, 5).EntireRow.Delete
            j = j + 1
        End If
    End If
```

Next j

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your comparing to Cells(j-1) before you fill Cells(j-1). But if I'm wrong about that, you need to loop backward through the range when you delete rows or Excel loses track of where you are.

```
Public Sub DeleteAllButLatest()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 9 To 3 Step -1
        If Base(Cells(i, 1).Value) = Base(Cells(i - 1, 1).Value) Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Public Function Base(ByVal sCode As String) As String

    Select Case Len(sCode)
        Case 13, 17
            Base = Left(sCode, Len(sCode) - 3)
        Case 16, 20
            Base = Left(sCode, Len(sCode) - 6)
    End Select

End Function
```

Based on your sample data in A2:A9. Only need to go to Row 3 because Row 2 will have to be good so no need to check it.  I made a function to return the "base" of each number so you can compare the base of the current cell to the cell above it. If they're the same, delete. If not, assume it's the latest.